# panda 3d importing module error

Tags: python, python-2.7, activepython, panda3d

I'm trying to learn panda 3d, but I'm getting this error

```
importerror no module named direct.showbase.showbase
```

I'm using the latest versions of panda 3d 1.7.2, python 2.7 on windows xp, how to fix the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.panda3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=10363

Panda 3D on Windows comes with a special version of python that is preconfigured to work correctly with Panda, that python is run with `ppython`.

Otherwise you need to add the Panda libraries to your Python path from the Panda install. There is a file called `panda3d.pth` which has the python path necessary, and you can copy that file to `C:\[Python Version]\Lib\site-packages`.

I don't know what Panda3d's version of python is, but you will need to be running that if you don't want to use `ppython`.

Comment: i try using ppython didn't work and as i explained on the other question i have no file called pyhon.ph

Comment: Update: [ppython is now legacy](http://www.panda3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=3471): "ppython.exe is identical to python.exe. It makes no difference which one you use. It exists only for historical reasons."