# ImportError: No module named pandac.PandaModules

Tags: python, parsing, panda3d

I'm trying to compile a *.exe using a *.py script.

http://pastebin.com/qpZz65aq

and I get the following error:

```
`ImportError: No module named pandac.PandaModules`
```

If you need further information, please ask.

Comment: Could you provide more information on the OS you are using?

Comment: I'm currently on Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: I currently have python 2.7.5 and Panda3D 1.9.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [panda 3d importing module error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370559/panda-3d-importing-module-error)

Comment: Check include file do not have this dependency. `NonRepeatableRandomSourceUD`

Comment: It is possible that you may use another approach? Like py2exe, the one introduced in this link: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

Comment: MarmiK, That didn't work.

Comment: I've done everything, I'm still getting this error.

Comment: Without much information, what I can say is that the tool you are using to create an .exe does not know the location of the Panda3D packages.  There is probably a way to tell it where the "pandac" directory is so that it can pick it up properly.

Comment: Same problem here. I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and using Python 2.7